# C# How do we use Object.GetHashCode()

Tags: c#, object, hash, hashcode, equality

Sure, hascodes are used in hastables and collections but what about that:

```
class TwoDPoint : System.Object{

   public readonly int x, y;

   //...left out some code

   public override int GetHashCode(){
      return x ^ y;
   }
}
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(VS.80).aspx
The snipped above directed me to the following sentence:

> You should not assume that equal hash codes imply object equality.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx

What I wonder is if we shouldn't always check for object equality after two hash codes match.
Consider the following two dots:

**P1.x = 2; P1.y = 4; Hash = 16**
and
**P2.x = 4; P2.y = 2; Hash = 16**

- If I only check the hash before inserting an item into a hashtable
  wouldn't that be a huge problem?
- Or is the this function maybe
  just used to provide a more performant way of checking "simmilarity"
  but always requires an equality check after a match?
- Or should I
  not care and just use the hashcode and assume it doesn't matter?

Comment: Yes, you *should* always check for object equality if two hash codes match.  Items that are equal must have the same hash code, but the *reverse* is not necessarily true.

Comment: The hash code is used to determine the "bucket" to store or look up an object in a hashed collection. 

So you, from user code, should not use the hash code to determine object (in)equality, just as the MSDN page tells you.

Maybe explain why you want to _"check the hash before inserting an item into a hashtable"_ and so on.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't want to call GetHashCode. I was just wondering how the method is used by the .NET Framework.